# How to find error from the return of function call?

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, ethers.js

The code is based on ethers.js. `meBid` is a function in a contract which places bid for user. Here is the function declaration in contract:

```
function meBid(address _bidItemAddress) external noBidder notComplete notDelisted returns (bool) { ....}
```

Here is how the function is called in React Native app with ethers:

```
import { ContractFactory, ethers } from "ethers";
let chres = await postContract.meBid(_trade.deployed_address);  //postContract is the contract and is valid
postContract.on("_meBid", async () => {
  //handle event after bid success.
})
```

Here is the return value of `chres`:

```
LOG  chainres :  {"chainId": 2018, "confirmations": 0, "data": "0x3ab0a29a00000000000000000000000089e10fa7794ac05ac820e9b0b68d4107f6509", "from": "0x882C5329a8fFe6570839eafF91e40cc5473063e0", "gasLimit": {"hex": "0x667b", "type": "BigNumber"}, "gasPrice": {"hex": "0x00", "type": "BigNumber"}, "hash": "0x8b4d1f1244e99859fcb1136b34f60413e9fe0d708f9c654a0072dbcefe3d7", "nonce": 122, "r": "0x2226e1b203e0b8902d064e8212d272fe8ee2894d6d86b45b7dd5c04cd663aa", "s": "0x4297e6a1004a20563a1de85a7a8db48e2ce12bd4b5fe247d124df4556509d0", "to": "0xadB0e387B5C600e4e01F4574A2116cD3df0fB", "type": null, "v": 4071, "value": {"hex": "0x00", "type": "BigNumber"}, "wait": [Function anonymous]}
```

But the `_meBid` event never called which means the function call to `meBid` didn't go through well. I check the Besu server log and didn't find any error on chain. The only thing I have is the value of `chres`. How to pin point the error here?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the listener for the event "_meBid" after awaiting the call to be mined. In order to listen for it setup the listener beforehand.

```
//postContract is the contract and is valid
postContract.on("_meBid", async () => {
  //handle event after bid success.
})
let chres = await postContract.meBid(_trade.deployed_address);
```

Another options is to search the transaction receipt for the event.

```
let chres = await postContract.meBid(_trade.deployed_address);

// Search in chres for the event
```