# Access a contract from within another contract of the same type with its deploy address in Solidity 0.8

Tags: solidity

A function of smart contract needs to access the contract of its same kind with contract's deploying address. Here is def of the contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract {

  uint256 public value=0;  //poster value
  uint256 public posterItemID;
  
  event _meBid(address _sender, uint256 _itemValue, uint256 _bidItemID);

  function bid(address _anotherMyContractAddress) external returns (bool) {. //_anotherMyContractAddress is the deploy address
    //generate smart contract from its address
    MyContract _mycon = MyContract(_anotherMyContractAddress);  //is this the right way???. The code seems not working when calling function bid
    //do something with _mycon
    uint256 _itemValue = _mycon.value();
    uint256 _bidItemID = _mycon.posterItemID();
    string memory _bidState = _mycon.returnState();
    if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_bidState)) != keccak256(abi.encodePacked("ForTrade"))) return false;  //function returnState() has been tested working and return a string
    //do other things normal

    emit _meBid(msg.sender, _itemValue, _bidItemID);  //fire event
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems fine to me. It just depends on the part you didn't show... `// do something with _mycon` many things can go wrong here, can you show what you are doing exactly ? Which parameter do you give to `_mycon.bid()` ? You may be creating an infinite loop...

Comment: added  _mycon related code to the post above. Other code is trivial.  `_bidItemAddress` is the only params passed in for the function. I have no clue about the error. Here is another post which shows the return value of the function call. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/129618/how-to-find-error-from-the-return-of-function-call

Comment: You never call `_mycon.bid()` ? It seemed like you would with your comment : `The code seems not working when calling function bid` ? If not, can you give more details over what you were expecting vs what happens ?

Comment: The function `bid` was called from front end with etherjs 5.6. But not for _mycon (whose address is passed in). purpose of _mycon is to access _mycon's params and change its state if needed.

Comment: @user938363 What does "The code seems not working" mean? It reverts, does nothing, does something unexpected, ..? You haven't provided enough code to test, the code provided seems to work. The problem might be in the code you haven't supplied, or some other problem like sending an incorrect address, or the called contract is failing for some other reason.